# Does the latest print edition of Dark Heresy contain errata?

Tags: warhammer-40k, dark-heresy-1e

Does the most recent printing of Dark Heresy have the errata worked into it?  I am using a damaged, first print run, Fantasy Flight Games copy of the book and want to know if it would be worth buying a newer print.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A crawl through the FFG forums reveals this:

http://new.fantasyflightgames.com/edge_foros_discusion.asp?efid=70&efcid=3&efidt=430473&efpag=0#430570

In short, it looks like the v1.0 Errata was included in the first reprint by FFG.  The Errata is currently up to v3.0, and there are currently no plans in place (so it seems) for a reprint that includes this.

Truthfully, if you have not picked up Black Crusade as of yet, I thoroughly reccomend it.  The rules refinements alone are worth the price, and it has been rumored that the changes being deployed (to the core rules, not necessarily character creation and advancement) there are going to reflect in the next iteration of Dark Heresy.

EDIT: Just noticed you have posted a black-crusade question, so I guess you already know that last part. :-)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the FFG edition includes some errata.

Note that the other games have differences mechanically from each other. Each is very close, but not the same mechanics, so if running a multi-corebook game, you'll need to pick which is dominant, anyway.